# Emulating ' find ' command in C

Tags: unix, find

What would be the best way to do this in the C programming language?

```
find fileName
```

Comment: Why not look at the `find` source code?

Comment: Check [this](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Walk_a_directory/Recursively#C) out.

Answer (score 4):

Look up the POSIX function [`nftw()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nftw.html).  It is designed as a 'new file tree walk' function.

There's a related but not immediately as useful function [`scandir()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scandir.html) which you might use.  The selection function might be used to invoke a recursive scan on sub-directories, for example, but `nftw()` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: I like that! Did not know about nftw until now. Really seems to be POSIX. I've even got it on my OS X.

Answer (score 2):

You could call `find` from a forked child process and get back `find`'s output from a pipe:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFSIZE 1000

int main(void) {
  int pfd[2], n;
  char str[BUFSIZE + 1];

  if (pipe(pfd) < 0) {
    printf("Oups, pipe failed.  Exiting\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  n = fork();

  if (n < 0) {
    printf("Oups, fork failed.  Exiting\n");
    exit(-2);
  } else if (n == 0) {
    close(pfd[0]);

    dup2(pfd[1], 1);
    close(pfd[1]);

    execlp("find", "find", "filename", (char *) 0);
    printf("Oups, execlp failed.  Exiting\n"); /* This will be read by the  parent. */
    exit(-1); /* To avoid problem if execlp fails, especially if in a loop. */
  } else {
    close(pfd[1]);

    while ((n = read(pfd[0], str, BUFSIZE)) > 0) {
      str[n] = '\0';
      printf("%s", str);
    }

    close(pfd[0]);
    wait(&n); /* To avoid the zombie process. */

    if (n != 0) {
       printf("Oups, find or execlp failed.\n");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a complex topic. Have a look at [the GNU libc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Accessing-Directories.html#Accessing-Directories). Then try to scan the current directory using scandir. If that works, you can implement a recursive version, assuming you are talking about the UNIX find command and want to do recursive search for file names.

Comment: See also [Working with Directory Trees](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Working-with-Directory-Trees.html#Working-with-Directory-Trees)